# Can't get auto increment after insert using Volley

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I'm trying to develop an android app, and I needed at some point to insert data into a MySQL database table ('demande') then retrieve the new record's auto increment key(demaynde_id), for this I used Volley library, I have noticed that the insertion is going smoothly , but when it comes to retrieving the key I couldn't get it and I got this error : **W/System.err: org.json.JSONException:
 Value < br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject**

This is my php file

**SendingbookingRequest.php**

```
<?php
require("password.php");
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "XXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXX");

$driver_id = $_POST["driver_id"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$adresse_source = $_POST["adresse_source"];
$duree = $_POST["duree"];
$distance = $_POST["distance"];
$response = array();
$dt_obj = new DateTime($response['send_moment'], new 
DateTimeZone('America/Chicago')); 
$dt_obj->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London')); 
$send_time = $dt_obj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
   echo $send_time;
 function AddRequest() {
    global $connect, $driver_id, $email, $adresse_source, $duree, $distance, $send_time ; 
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO demande (driver_id, pass_id, adresse_source, duree, distance, send_moment) VALUES (?, (SELECT user_id FROM passager WHERE email = ?),?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "issdis", $driver_id, $email, $adresse_source, $duree, $distance, $send_time); 
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

}
  function getDemandeId() {
       global $connect,$driver_id, $email;
$statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM demande WHERE driver_id = ? AND pass_id = (SELECT user_id FROM passager WHERE email = ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"is", $driver_id, $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $demande_id); 
   while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){ 
         $response["demande_id"] = $demande_id;


}       
}

$response["success"] = false;  

    AddRequest();
    getDemandeId();
    $response["success"] = true;  


echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

I've tried to remove the getDemandeId(), insertion succeeded but I got the same error in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the response ? Is it correctly formatted Try logging the response you get and see if it's properly formatted.
This exception occurs when you try to convert a string into jsonObject which is not correctly formatted

Comment: I've tried, but I couldn't do it, simply because when I tried to replace the '?' with real values I had to remove the variables from function2 and that got me an error :Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt_bind_param() in /storage/h3/744/754744/public_html/SendBookingReq.php on line 26

Comment: If that is a question, than my answer is yes, I did use it a lot and it worked

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: driver_id in /storage/h3/744/754744/public_html/SendBookingReq.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: email in ......etc etc 
2017-04-23 15:57:47{"success":true}

Comment: Could you please help me, I really need it

Comment: There seems to be a problem in your php script I am not too thorough in php I know android I will try though

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it